# How can I leverage Azure AD B2C to create and manage users through a REST API?

Tags: azure, authentication, microservices, azure-ad-b2c, identity

I'm trying to create an application in a microservices architecture. I'm currently trying to figure out the authentication and authorization part. I've done some research and opted for Azure AD B2C as the identity provider.

What I want right now is a way to create users within my Azure AD B2C through an REST API that I will expose to my clients (web applications and mobile clients). I've been exploring the Azure AD B2C documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/) for some time now, and even the Azure AD B2C interface, but all the information regarding signin and signup that I was able to find it's related to allow users to perform these actions via a customisable page with company branding.

That's not what I need. I want to expose several services behind an API gateway and allow my client applications to perform the creation, and management of my users. I want my mobile team to be able to call my API, register a user, perform signin, and be able to access the other business related services without even knowing if I'm using Azure AD B2C or not. But so far I was't able to find any Azure AD B2C API that will allow me to do that. Can I achieve that with Microsoft Azure AD B2C or should I start looking into other cloud identity providers?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to manage Azure AD B2C users with Rest API, you can use Microsoft Graph API to implement it. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview)

For example

- **Register application**

  1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
  2. Select the **Directory + Subscription** icon in the portal toolbar, and then select the directory that contains your Azure AD B2C tenant.
  3. In the Azure portal, search for and select **Azure AD B2C**.
  4. Select App registrations (Preview), and then select New registration.
  5. Enter a Name for the application. For example, managementapp1.
  6. Select **Accounts in this organizational directory only**.
  7. Under **Permissions**, clear the Grant admin consent to openid and offline_access permissions check box.
  8. Select **Register**.
  9. Record the **Application (client) ID** that appears on the application overview page. You use this value in a later step.
- **Grant API permissions**

  1. Under **Manage**, select **API permissions**.
  2. Under **Configured permissions**, select **Add a permission**.
  3. Select the **Microsoft APIs** tab, then select **Microsoft Graph**.
  4. Select **Application permissions**.
  5. Expand the appropriate permission group and select the check box of the permission to grant to your management application. For example: Directory > Directory.ReadWrite.All: For user migration or user management scenarios.
  6. Select **Add permissions**. As directed, wait a few minutes before proceeding to the next step.
  7. Select **Grant admin consent for (your tenant name)**.
  8. Select your currently signed-in administrator account, or sign in with an account in your Azure AD B2C tenant that's been assigned at least the Cloud application administrator role.
  9. Select **Accept**.
  10. Select **Refresh**, and then verify that "Granted for ..." appears under Status. It might take a few minutes for the permissions to propagate.
- **Create Client secret**

  1. Under **Manage**, select **Certificates & secrets**.
  2. Select New **client secret**.
- **Get access token**

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your b2c tannat name >/oauth2/v2.0/token 

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<your sp appId>
&client_secret=<you sp password>
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

- **Create User**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>

{

      "displayName": "[TEST] Bridgette Harmon (Local account)",
      "givenName": "Bridgette",
      "surname": "Harmon",
      "identities": [
        {
             "signInType": "userName",
             "issuer": "<your b2c tenant>",
            "issuerAssignedId": "Bridgette"
        }
      ],

      "passwordProfile" : {
          "password": "password-value",
          "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I am looking for a centralized way to keep my users and to perform Single Sign On from multiple applications, or api. I am leaning towards developing my own Identity Provider at this point vs Azure AD for a cost basis standpoint.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

To amplify @JimXu answer, use this [client](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet) as an example.

"This approach is similar to a service account scenario where the application acts as itself, not as a user that signed-in via an interactive user login. This is done by using the OAuth 2.0 **client credentials grant**."